# Sciopta RTOS assembly error

Tags: assembly, rtos

I don't know much about assembly, but when I was trying to build a project that uses Sciopta RTOS and Cortex A processor, it produced the following error:

```
    Error[401]: Operand syntax error
    mrc     p15, #0, r0, c9, c14, #2
-----------------^
```

In the file cortex_a.s

Does anyone have an idea about this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error code and text, it looks like you are using the IAR assembler, but the .s extension is a GNU assembler convention, so possibly the code is written for the GNU assembler rather they IAR and they differ in this respect.

My guess would be to remove the # since there is no option other than an immediate operand so it is implicit.  This is supported by the release notes [here](http://supp.iar.com/FilesPublic/UPDINFO/007040/arm/doc/infocenter/iasmarm.ENU.html), which have the following note:

> In EWARM 6.50.2:
>
> The instructions MCR and MRC now allow # before operation code operands also in Thumb mode.
>
> [EW23559]

Presumably your version of EWARM is older?

Comment: yes, you are correct about this, I tried a more recent version of IAR assembler, and it worked.